# AngularJS sum of value with if condition

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in AngularJS view. I have some values with if condition and I want to calculate their sum. It was working well before if condition but after adding if condition, some problem occurred and it is showing result as NaN.
Here is my code.

```
<div ng-if = "nnn == 'yes'">
<h3>Sale Roakker (Naam)</h3>
<div class="card-content table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Total</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in sales_items_detail">
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.item_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ (x.amount).toFixed(2) }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td><strong>{{amount_sale = amountTotal(sales_items_detail)}}</strong></td>
              </tr>                            
        </tfoot>
    </table>                        
</div>
</div>
<div ng-if = "nnn == 'not'">
<h3>Sale Roakker (Naam)</h3>
<div class="card-content table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Total</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in sales_items_detail">
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.item_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.price*x.quantity }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td><strong>{{amount_sale = saleTotal(sales_items_detail)}}</strong></td>
              </tr>                            
        </tfoot>
    </table>                        
</div>
</div>
<h3>Naqdi Roakker Jama</h3>
<div class="card-content table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
                <th>Amount</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in transection_detail_jama">
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.detail }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.amount }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td><strong>{{amount_jama = amountTotal(transection_detail_jama)}}</strong></td>
              </tr>              
        </tfoot>
    </table>                        
</div>
<h3>Naqdi Roakker Naam</h3>
<div class="card-content table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
                <th>Amount</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in transection_detail_naam">
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.detail }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.amount }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td><strong>{{ amount_naam = amountTotal(transection_detail_naam)}}</strong></td>
              </tr>            
        </tfoot>
    </table>                        
</div>
total = {{(parseFloat(amount_sale) + parseFloat(amount_naam)) - (parseFloat(amount_jama)) }}
```

If I remove if condition then it works well but with if condition it is not working and shows NaN.
I think here is a problem with same variable name `amount_sale`. 
Please help me if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing ng-if to ng-show

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs does not assign value to a variable like this it will directly show what will be returned through amountTotal(sales_items_detail) function

```
{{amount_sale = amountTotal(sales_items_detail)}}
```

You should add all this code logic in the controller and only use the resulted variable in the double brackets
see this example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<div ng-if="obj">{{val = "wow"}}</div>
<div ng-if="obj">{{val = "how"}}</div>
<div>{{val}}</div>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {  
    $scope.obj = true;
    $scope.val ="ok";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```